# API to get and set team prefs

Tags: slack-api

There seems to be an undocumented api to get the team preferences (admin settings) which is called from the web UI. However, I am not able to find any related documentation for similar GET api.
Please let us know how do we read and set admin settings in a slack workspace.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is the place to ask for details upon some vendor API.

Comment: I am collecting all known undocumented API methods in this [github](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc). However, I do not include web UI methods, because they usually require a runtime token and can not be used with other tokens.

Comment: And I am currently not aware of any API method to fetch the team settings.

Comment: @Eric, thanks a lot for your response. Yes I did check your list on github and did not find any such method and hence the question. Is there any plan to publish an api to query team settings, or any other kind of deep integration possible?